# Led matrix with hole cut out

Tags: video, led

I'm a student artist with a decent background in robotics/cs working on a sculpture and was hoping to use a raspberry pi and a led matrix. I was hoping to cut out a section in the middle of the matrix in the shape of a square while still being able to send video to the rest of the leds as if it were there. Any recommendations on where to start or a system that can handle this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by `LED matrix`?

Comment: a question about modifying a led matrix is not about Raspberry Pi ... please edit your post to make it on topic here